# Query to get all the posts of more than 2 meta_value having same meta_key?

Tags: wp-query, metabox, meta-value

Meta_value will have checkbox  infront of them so when both the check box is selected posts related to both the meta_value will be displayed.

Comment: What query method are you using? WP_Query()? get_posts()? wpdb object? You should be able to achieve it with WP_Query http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I m using WP_Query() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query:

```
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'my_custom_post_type',
   'meta_key' => 'age',
   'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
   'order' => 'ASC',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'age',
           'value' => array(3, 4),
           'compare' => 'IN',
       )
   )
 );
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Look at the meta_query section. you can define the key and then all the possible values in a array. You can also define the type of comparison (eg. great than, equal, IN).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and the correct answer sir.